# I can not get the "lxr " throught apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, lxr

everyone. Firstly, forgive my poor English #_#

I use ubuntu 11.10 now.

And I want to install lxr.But I can not get it throught

*sudo apt-get install lxr*.

The apt-get can not find the lxr.

I had google for this problem, but failed.

Could you tell me where to download the "lxr",please?

Or tell me how to make the apt-get find the "lxr"?

Thanks!

Comment: LXR package in Oneiric: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/lxr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download lxr from this location:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/files/stable/

The official installation guide is here: http://lxr.sourceforge.net/en/1-0-InstallSteps/1-0-install.php

Since the site is constantly evolving, the preferred access method is navigation from the home page http://lxr.sourceforge.net/en/index.php